# Append FOR Loop output to List PYTHON

Tags: python, list, for-loop

i'm just trying to write output of for loop to txt file

```
for filename in glob.glob('/home/*.txt'):
    file_metadata = { 'name': 'files.txt', 'mimeType': '*/*' }
    media = MediaFileUpload(filename, mimetype='*/*', resumable=True)
    file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
    links = []
    links.append(file.get('id'))
    with open("ids.txt", "w") as file:
        for e in links:
            file.write(str(e))
            file.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write to the file in a separate loop, not nested loop, or just remove the nested loop entirely. You should also remove `close()` from `with open()`, it handles the closing after the writing to the file is done

```
with open("ids.txt", "w") as f:
    for filename in glob.glob('/home/*.txt'):
        file_metadata = { 'name': 'files.txt', 'mimeType': '*/*' }
        media = MediaFileUpload(filename, mimetype='*/*', resumable=True)
        file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
        f.write(f'{file.get("id")}\n')
        # or if your Python version is older than 3.6
        f.write(str(file.get("id")) + '\n')
```

Comment: you forgot a separator for links, they will be written as one humongous line with no possibility to separate one from another.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the same variable `file` for two different purposes. And you should not `close()` anything you open with `with open() as ..`:

```
links = []
for filename in glob.glob('/home/*.txt'):
    file_metadata = { 'name': 'files.txt', 'mimeType': '*/*' }
    media = MediaFileUpload(filename, mimetype='*/*', resumable=True)
    file = drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
    links.append(file.get('id'))

with open("ids.txt", "w") as fout:
    fout.write('\n'.join(links))
```